# Why can a set of random variables be called a sample?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, expected-value, sample

I am trying to understand this slide on sample means.

I understand the meaning of the word sample [to be a set of individual objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%20and%20quantitative%20research,points%2C%20sampling%20units%20or%20observations.) as if grabbing a handful of jellybeans from a packet.

Yet in this slide, when the jellybeans are themselves random variables, why is it called a sample?

The slide does not state that it is talking about a "Random Sample" Should it?

[image: Sample Means]